# value vs pointer assigned to a slice

Tags: go

I'm working my way through this "Tour of Go" and I'm doing this exercise [here](https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/18). I originally wrote the answer like this:

```
func Pic(dx, dy int) [][]uint8 {
    outer := make([][]uint8, dy)
    inner := make([]uint8, dx)

    for y, _ := range outer {       
        for x, _ := range inner {
            inner[x] = x^y // this is one of the image functions they give
        }

        outer[y] = inner
    }
    return outer
}
```

I thought this should work, but when I run `Pic(5,5)` I get:

```
[[0 4 8 12 16] [0 4 8 12 16] [0 4 8 12 16] [0 4 8 12 16] [0 4 8 12 16]]
```

Not right, obviously.

So, I finally figured out that I needed to move my `inner := make([]uint8, dx)` declaration *inside* of the first loop like so:

```
func Pic(dx, dy int) [][]uint8 {
    outer := make([][]uint8, dy)

    for y, _ := range outer {
        inner := make([]uint8, dx)

        for x, _ := range inner {
            inner[x] = x^y // this is one of the image functions they give
        }

        outer[y] = inner
    }
    return outer
}
```

and now `Pic(5,5)` gives me the correct answer:

```
[[0 0 0 0 0] [0 1 2 3 4] [0 2 4 6 8] [0 3 6 9 12] [0 4 8 12 16]]
```

What's happening here? I *think* this has something to do with pointers or something, but I want to be sure I really understand what's going on. Obviously, in the first example, each time I reassigned something new to `inner` the values in `outer` that previously had `inner` assigned to them changed as well.

But what happens in the second example? Each time we go through the `range outer` loop the `inner` variable gets re-declared, but what happens to the values of `outer` that previously had `inner` assigned to them? Are they now somehow "cut off" and only exist as copies?

I'm mainly confused because the assignment line `outer[y] = inner` doesn't change in either example, so I don't understand the mechanics of how in one of them it assigns a copy of the value and in the other it assigns what I would think of as a pointer.

Comment: The first example creates one inner slice and uses it multiple time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first case, you never "reassigned something new to `inner`". You created one slice of `uint8`, called `inner`, which you filled with values (overwriting those values several times), and you made *every element of `outer`* contain a copy of `inner`. But remember, a slice is only a view into an array that exists somewhere (in your case, the backing array is created anonymously by `make`). Copying a slice doesn't copy the values in the array, it just copies the slice header, meaning there are now multiple views onto the same storage (this is fine, and safe).

In the second case, you called `make` for every row of `outer`, so five different backing arrays were created, with `inner` pointing into a different one each time. This time, when you assigned `inner` to an element of `outer`, you got five genuinely different slice headers, instead of five copies of the same one.

In short: a slice is a value, but it's a value that contains a pointer. The pointer might point to an array that has a name, or it might point to an entirely anonymous array. There's nothing to worry about; Go will make sure that anything that is pointed-to stays alive.

Comment: Thank you. This is the key part I was missing: `a slice is only a view into an array that exists somewhere (in your case, the backing array is created anonymously by make)`. I forgot about that principle of slices. Very helpful. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

First, consider this:

```
inner := make([]uint8, dx)
```

This statement allocates an array large enough to hold `dx` elements, creates a slice from it, and stores that slice in the variable `inner`. A slice contains three values: a pointer to the underlying array, capacity of that array, and the length of the slice. So `inner` contains a pointer to the actual data.

When you redeclare and assign `inner` in the for loop, a new array is created to store the data, `inner` becomes a slice pointing to that array, and then you fill out the individual elements of `inner`. Then you assign `inner` to an element of `outer`, and that element of `outer` now gets that slice, pointing to the initialized data. In the next iteration, a new array is created, `inner` is assigned to it, etc.

So it's got to do with pointers, in particular, the fact that a slice contains a pointer to the underlying array, and that when you assign a variable to a slice, that variable is assigned three values, the pointer to array, length, and capacity,

Comment: Thank you, this explains it but the other answer was both first and little more clear. Thanks again though.